# Is it possible to dynamically set the preferred language of a google custom search engine

Tags: settings, dynamically-generated, google-custom-search

Say I have a website in two languages each under its own domain:

- websitename.com
- websitename.fr

Both have a paid custom search engine. In the future more websites with will be added for other languages. This will dramatically increase the costs for the custom search engines.

I'd rather have a single search engine that searches all of the websites, but with a preferred language set by me depending on what website loads the engine. This way a visitor on websitename.fr will have French pages ranked higher.

Google CSE supports searching multiple websites and setting a preferred language. I can't seem to find how to alter this setting dynamically when loading the engine in one of the websites. Is this possible at all, or is my only option to have a different CSE for each website?

Answer (score 1):

```
gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?language=fr&cx=' + cx;
```

Just add `language` parameter in src to cse.js.